# Get a random value from a list in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a substitution table in the form of a dictionary. I need to loop through a string and substitute each char based on a table like the example.

How would I replace `"rrFrd?F??-rd?-drr"` (example) with a random assignment from my table? Each char is the key and I need to replace it with one of the tuples in its list `r` = `a` or `e` or `q` and so on through the string. I don't know how to access the dictionary list with the given key and get a random letter from that list.

```
 {'r': [('a', 0.7), ('e', 0.3), ('q', 0.1)], 'F': [('b', 0.6), (',', 0.3),    ('m', 0.1)], 'd': [('r', 0.5), ('.', 0.2), ('?', 0.2), ('(', 0.1)], '-': [('p', 0.4), ('f', 0.2), ('n', 0.1), ('@', 0.1)]}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you taken a look at `random.choice`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've understood your requirement correctly, the easiest way to choose an option from the list in the dictionary indexed on the relevant key, would be to use `random.choice(yourdict[character])[0]` - that would return the a random letter from one of the tuples in the list for that key.

For example:

```
import random

x = "rrFrd?F??-rd?-drr"
y = {'r': [('a', 0.7), ('e', 0.3), ('q', 0.1)], 'F': [('b', 0.6), (',', 0.3),    ('m', 0.1)], 'd': [('r', 0.5), ('.', 0.2), ('?', 0.2), ('(', 0.1)], '-': [('p', 0.4), ('f', 0.2), ('n', 0.1), ('@', 0.1)]}
z = ""

for character in x:
    if y.get(character) != None:
        z += random.choice(y[character])[0]
    else:
        z += character

print(z)
```

That creates a new string, z, with each character that has a key in the dictionary replaced by one of the tuple entries, and characters that aren't in the dictionary simply passed through. E.g.

`[0] aqber?,??pq??p(ee`

`[1] qebq.?b??@qr?n.ae`

Answer (score 1):

First of all your dict is missing the key `'?'` and not all probabilities add up to one. Here is a correct dict for your example :

```
d = {'r': [('a', 0.7), ('e', 0.2), ('q', 0.1)], 
     'F': [('b', 0.6), (',', 0.3), ('m', 0.1)],
     'd': [('r', 0.5), ('.', 0.2), ('?', 0.2), ('(', 0.1)], 
     '-': [('p', 0.4), ('f', 0.2), ('n', 0.1), ('@', 0.3)],
     '?': [(' ', 1)]}
```

To chose a random character with its according probability you can use `numpy.random.choice`. Here is a minimal code :

```
import numpy as np

d = {'r': [('a', 0.7), ('e', 0.2), ('q', 0.1)], 
     'F': [('b', 0.6), (',', 0.3), ('m', 0.1)],
     'd': [('r', 0.5), ('.', 0.2), ('?', 0.2), ('(', 0.1)], 
     '-': [('p', 0.4), ('f', 0.2), ('n', 0.1), ('@', 0.3)],
     '?': [(' ', 1)]}

s = "rrFrd?F??-rd?-drr"
new_s = ""

for char in s:
    new_chars_list = [i[0] for i in d[char]]
    proba_chars = [i[1] for i in d[char]]
    new_char = np.random.choice(a=new_chars_list, size=1, p=proba_chars)
    new_s += new_char[0]

print new_s
```